# Résumé conventions: present, past, and continuous tenses

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

When writing a résumé or CV, I’ve read that:

> - Use the present tense when referring to accomplishments that are
>   ongoing.
> - Use the past tense (ending in *–ed*) when referring to accomplishments
>   that you have completed.

Does ***present tense*** mean “present simple” only, or is “present continuous” also right?

For example, I want to add a new entry on my CV saying:

> - Awaiting a new assignment as an external consultant.
> - Researching and taking training on. . . .

Is that right, or should I use the present simple instead?

Comment: OT, but it's either "waiting for X" or "awaiting X" with no *for*. Also, it's "assignment", one E.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing advice. 

Comment: This isn't writing advice, it's ***grammar***. Compare [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36113/is-it-normal-in-english-to-talk-about-oneself-in-the-third-person-in-these-cases/36231#36231), which wasn't closed.

Answer (score 2):

For résumés, in general you should use present continuous when the entry is temporary and simple present when it's permanent. For example: *"knows 27 programming languages well"* should be in simple present, and *"learning Prolog, F#, and Haskell"* should be in present continuous. And here the boundary between "temporary" and "permanent" is fuzzy. I don't have any guidelines for deciding on questionable entries; you should use your best judgment.

Comment: Thanks. This is in general, but what about resumés?, Should I apply exactly the same rules?, Or is more common to use the present simple?

Comment: Then I will use the continuous form because is temporary.